# Oracle SQL ALTER TABLE error

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

I have code like this:

```
  ALTER TABLE "VMA_CSDD" ADD CONSTRAINT "VMA_CSDD_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
  ALTER TABLE "VMA_CSDD" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE)
  ALTER TABLE "VMA_CSDD" MODIFY ("CSDD_NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE)
```

**It gives me an error:**

```
ALTER TABLE "VMA_CSDD" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE)
```

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Option `ENABLE` is not correct with column definition you have to also add types

```
 ALTER TABLE "VMA_CSDD" MODIFY ("ID" int NOT NULL )
 ALTER TABLE "VMA_CSDD" MODIFY ("CSDD_NAME" varchar(100) NOT NULL )
```